# SSIS cant change Enumerators ADONET variable

Tags: visual-studio-2015, ssis, windows-10

I am trying to change enumerators variable but there is a bug i cant see anything.
tried changing resolutions from 4k to fullHD and others still not working.

[image]

Funny thing is that in another project it works
[image]

EDIT: doesnt work with any new project and doesnt work when i try to import project using integration services wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix it by going to

> Solution Explorer (Right Click on Project) > Properties >
>   Configuration Properties > General > Change Server Version to SQL
>   Server 2016 instead of SQL Server vnext